# Angular - $rootScope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular 1.5 app (a SPA), I use user profile information on every "page" of the app.  So, in my app.js file, I include the following code:

```
$http.get(API_URL + "/user")
            .then(function success(response){
                $rootScope.userInfo = response.data;
            },
            function error(response){

            });
```

And then in each component's controller and template, I make reference to this object like the following:

```
<img class="profile icon" ng-src="{{$rootScope.userInfo.profile_photo}}">
```

However, the image never shows up. I assume because the callback setting the $rootScope.userInfo from the response is called after the template has been loaded.  How do I ensure it gets updated when the response comes in from the GET call?

EDIT - Here's more info, since the answers coming in about "don't use $rootScope in the view" isn't working for me.  Making the changes suggested doesn't work.  Do I need to reference $ctrl in this case?

```
angular.module('xxx')
        .component("navBar", {
            templateUrl: "/components/navBar/navBar.html",
            controller: NavBarController,
            bindings: {

            }
        });

function NavBarController($rootScope, $scope, $uibModal, $timeout, $http, API_URL) {
        var vm = this;
```

Comment: I believe you do NOT have to prefix the path with `$rootScope`, i.e. try `ng-src="{{userInfo.profile_photo}}"`.

Comment: scopes are ***always*** isolate in a component.  see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#!/.  Therefore, components do not inherit from or have access to `$rootScope`.  Using `$rootScope` is considered by many to be an anti-pattern anyway;  It is recommended to use a service to store persistent data, and a requirement to use a service when in combination with components.  While you *might* be able to use `$root` to get around this restriction, this is not recommended behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the view is bound to the `$scope` already, you never write the following

```
<img class="profile icon" ng-src="{{$scope.userInfo.profile_photo}}">
```

instead

```
<img class="profile icon" ng-src="{{userInfo.profile_photo}}">
```

All scopes, except isolate scopes, have inheritance and the `$rootScope` is at the top of that chain, so as long as no other `$scope` have a `userInfo` property in that chain writting

```
<img class="profile icon" ng-src="{{userInfo.profile_photo}}">
```

will point to the property in the `$rootScope`

If you are inside a isolate scope you could write

```
<img class="profile icon" ng-src="{{$root.userInfo.profile_photo}}">
```

since all scopes, even isolated, have a `$root` property that points to the `$rootScope`

Check here

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    // An empty controller to create a new scope
    // Only for demonstration of inheritance 
  })
  .directive('directive', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: '<div>{{$root.userInfo.name}}</div>'
    };
  })
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.userInfo = {
      name: 'John'
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div>{{userInfo.name}}</div>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    {{userInfo.name}}
  </div>
  <directive></directive>
</div>
```

Comment: as I mention in my comment, components are always isolate, and `$root` may be necessary, but not recommended for this situation.

Comment: @Claies I'm aware, but as long as the OP does not change how his app is designed this is a working solution for him. You don't know for sure the cost of the change and even if he changes how that works, then it will be subject for another question. For his present problem this is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just use,

```
<img class="profile icon" ng-src="{{userInfo.profile_photo}}">
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/p6d54mde/1/)**

Comment: Please see my edits.  This solution didn't work, probably because of how I set up the component

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to put `$rootScope` in view
you should put like this

```
<img class="profile icon" ng-src="{{userInfo.profile_photo}}">
```

Comment: What is different from the answer i gave?

Comment: @Sajeetharan that he posted it 2 seconds after you and didn't see your answer

Comment: Not 2 secs actually 1 minute

Comment: @Sajeetharan, site didnt updated till i post my answer.So i didnt see your answer.Good catch friend

Comment: @Nikhil it happens,but i thought your answer is different